# Encoding a cipher

Tags: python, string, encoding, decode

Question:
It’s time to practice our spy craft and encode a simple cipher. Write a function encode() that asks the user for the message to be encoded and for an integer key value. The cipher will shift each character in the message by adding the key to the character’s Unicode value. For example, ‘A’ (unicode 65) shifted 3 produces ‘D’ (unicode 68).

Please make sure your output is only the cipher text.

The output should be:

enter a message: **The time has come, the Walrus said**

enter a key: **7**

**[ol'{ptl'ohz'jvtl3'{ol'^hsyz'zhpk**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are not a script writing service. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple [caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)
Here is the code anyway

```py
def encrypt(text, s):
    result = ""
    # transverse the plain text
    for i in range(len(text)):
        char = text[i]
        # Encrypt uppercase characters in plain text
        if (char.isupper()):
            result += chr((ord(char) + s-65) % 26 + 65)
        # Encrypt lowercase characters in plain text
        else:
            result += chr((ord(char) + s - 97) % 26 + 97)
    return result
```

Comment: @SashSinha my bad, I just copy-pasted code from the internet, couldn't be bothered to check its validity. It works now tho

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using **[`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr)**, **[`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)**, and [`str.join(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord):

```py
def get_int_input(prompt: str) -> int:
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print('Error: Enter an integer, try again...')


def encode(message: str, key: int) -> str:
    return ''.join(chr(ord(ch) + key) for ch in message)


def main() -> None:
    message = input('Enter a message: ')
    key = get_int_input('Enter a key: ')
    encoded = encode(message, key)
    print(encoded)

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter a message: The time has come, the Walrus said
Enter a key: 7
[ol'{ptl'ohz'jvtl3'{ol'^hsy|z'zhpk
```

Comment: Sash I appreciate your time and help a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chr()` and `ord()` to shift each character and `join()` to put the result back together:

```
s = "The time has come, the Walrus said"
k = 7

e = "".join(chr(ord(c)+k) for c in s)

print(e)
[ol'{ptl'ohz'jvtl3'{ol'^hsy|z'zhpk
```

Comment: Alain Thank you so much! i'm new to python and my prof is killing me with these questions